# I cannot expand an accordeon section with rspec/capybara

Tags: rspec, capybara

I have been struggling for a while now but can't find a solution myself or a good tip using google.

This is my accordeon code

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" >
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a href="collapse1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1" id="OT">
          Oude Testament
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
and so on for the underlying text and the second panel
```

I have tried to open it using the following code in rspec/capybara:

```
x = page.find_by_id('OT')
click_on(x)
```

Or with

```
x = page.find_link('Oude Testament')
click_on(x)
```

Or with

```
x = find_link("a[href$='collapse1']")
```

When I debug, I see that x gets assigned, so that look good.
But I never see the accordeon opening (although it works ok in a browser).

Any tips?

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: I guess I am using selenium, I can't find I have configured something, so it should be selenium as default

Comment: The default (for tests not tagged with `js:true`) is rack-test which does not support JS.   If you are using selenium it will be opening a firefox instance on your desktop when you run the tests - if that isn't happening you're using rack-test and no JS will do anything - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click_on` is an alias for `click_link_or_button` which from the docs - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#click_link_or_button-instance_method - takes either the id, text, or value of a link or button, it does not take an element.  Therefore, assuming you are using a JS capable driver (not rack-test), you should be able to use any of the following

```
page.click_on('OT')
page.click_on('Oude Testament') 
page.click_link('OT')
page.click_link('Oude Testament')
page.find_link('OT').click
page.find_link('Oude Testament').click
```

Your third attempt (find_link("a[href$='collapse1']")) is passing a CSS selector to find_link which it doesn't take.  From the docs - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#find_link-instance_method - it takes id or text of the link.  It also supports a :href option, so to match what you were attempting to do it would be

```
page.find_link(href: /collapse1$/).click
```

In the future please post the actual errors you get from your attempts since it will make it easier for people to provide you answers.

Comment: @andreheijstek You're welcome - if it helps you don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so the question gets marked as answered

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer.
But, the all options resulted in:
'ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/collapse1"'

Comment: @andreheijstek That would tend to indicate you don't have any JS catching the clicks so the normal click behavior is happening and trying to follow the href.  Either you have errors in your JS or you're not using a JS capable driver.

Comment: OK. I have now added js: true to my scenario (stupid, I should have known that). But now the test is failing with the next assert. 
'expect(page).to have_content("Genesis")`
which is the line that *is* shown when I open the accordeon. So it still seems that the click is not working

Comment: @andreheijstek Since it was attempting to navigate previously and now it's not - the click is doing something.  Check for JS errors in the dev console, check the case of the text you're looking for, etc.  Without the HTML it's impossible to say anymore.

Comment: @andreheijstek Another potential issue is if "Genesis" is supposed to be coming from data in the database, if you haven't disabled transactional testing and configured database_cleaner correctly the data may not actually be visible to the app while being tested.

Comment: "Genesis" is indeed coming from the database, but I have database_cleaner installed correctly, I think.

`RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:deletion)
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end`

And 

`config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`

The full HTML is here: https://gist.github.com/andreheijstek/45018683df6ca6373627870d6114a597

Comment: @andreheijstek Update your database cleaner config to match the recommended config - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example -  The `append_after` vs `after` is important for reducing test flakiness and the rest just makes for nice usage (you can change the :truncation instances to :deletion if thats what you prefer).   I also just noticed that the href in your link is "collapse1" when it should be "#collapse1" which will probably make the accordion actually work.

Comment: Still no luck. I now see Firefox opening. I think I also see the click happening, because the link gets underlined, but the accordeon does not open.
To be clear, the accordeon is working fine when I just run it in my dev.env. But it does not open from my test.

Comment: I now changed the text in the accordeon to some hardcoded text instead of text from the database. And now it is working! So it must be something with the database / some locking or so. At least another direction for debugging!

Comment: @andreheijstek  Then you need to pause the test after the click and look in the firefox developer console for errors, check whether the accordion has opened but is empty because you're DB objects aren't loading, etc.  I am curious how it works in dev when the href value is definitely wrong in the code you posted.

Comment: @andreheijstek  It sounds like either you're not creating the DB objects in your test, or your database cleaner/transaction mode setup is not actually correct - either way it's pretty much moved beyond this question.

Comment: Me stupid. I actually did not create the data in the test. I complete redesigned my page to use the accordeon, and started anew with my test, but forgot to create the data.
Thanks a lot for your help and patience with a newbe.